# Advice with the deployment strategy to follow with NextJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, next.js, isomorphic-javascript

Could you recommend us the best practices to deploy applications in production with nextjs?

We are thinking in strategies like: canary deployment, blue/green deployment... We have several doubts to handle BUILD_ID.

Right now, with this kind of strategies we are facing with this error:

> INVALID_BUILD_ID, because in some moment of the deployment we have at
>   least two different versions of the application.

for example:

On a Canary deployment, at one point we have 2 different versions, The balancer send a client to
version A, but then when the client need other resources, the balancer could send this request to a
server with version B. At this point the client receive a 500 error when the app fetches resources like serp.js, _error.js, _document.js, and the webpage is not loaded correctly.

```
_next/f6bff019-9550-4029-99fa-2b33a50045f6/page/index.js ---> old (previous deployment)

_next/005b2202-c5b2-4de6-afd8-1c8451d16ab3/page/index.js ---> new (current deployment)
```

Until now, we have tested:

1. Rename the BUILD_ID to have the same hash in both versions, but we think is a bad practice, because we think that the client's cache will not be refreshed how is expected.
2. Sticky sessions are the most reliable, but we handle a stateless app as an app with the state, and really is not true.
3. We could put on front a CDN that caches the BUILD_ID, but we are not sure that the time we should assign for the cache of the js files.

Comment: This appears to be a real problem.. I'm just curious. Even if NextJS was not in the picture, putting old and new versions of the app behind the same load balance would cause problems for the same reasons too, right? Perhaps deploying them as separate applications and using another layer to do session based A/B testing might alleviate this problem

Comment: If your deployments happen in the same order (Server A > B > C) every time, see this : https://serverfault.com/questions/537269/nginx-reverse-proxy-try-upstream-a-then-b-then-a-again . We have two configs, fallback for deployment / load balanced for production, which we symlink to nginx config.

Comment: @alberto, what did you come up with a solution?

Answer (score -2):

I would recommend you to follow the [JAMStack](https://jamstack.org/) pattern for deploying NextJs applications.

**Vercel** offers the best deploying and hosting service for NextJS , you can start for **free**

You can follow this [guide](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/deploying-nextjs-app)

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it's there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Also read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: "just use vercel" (while probably the cheaper answer for teams looking at reinventing the wheel) doesn't answer the question.